# How would you make it so a list of dataframes can be reassigned based on another list of names in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I read in 4 dataframes as a list and would like to be able to call on them as if I individually read them in and don't want to do it by using `name = df_list[0]` for each one. is there a way to do that for all of them automatically if i have list of names indexed in the order i want the data frames to be named. I was thinking a for loop with an if statement based on the indexes matching but got stuck how to finish it

```
files = glob('*.json')
dataframes = [pd.read_json(f) for f in files]
list_of_df_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4 ']
for df in dataframes:
    if dataframe.index() == list_of_df_names.index() # got stuck here can't seem to get to figure out the rest
```

edit* 03/01/2020 20:54
to clarify im trying to figure out if i can make the end result essentially work so that i can do 
    `name1.head()` 
or `name2.head()` and still get the same result of `named_dfs['name1']` if i had linked them via dictionary. And yes the file names are the same as the names in the list. no particular practical reason just curios if its possible

Comment: As your description, you should use dictionary instead list to store all your dataframes. After storing them in dictionary, you just call them through `key` as normal dictionary accessing such as `dataframes['name1']` ....

Answer (score 1):

if the names are the file name then you could do

```py
df_dict = {name: pd.read_json(name) for f in glob('*.json')}
```

and call them by name

```py
df_dict['name1'] = first_dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

you can zip both iterables and turn them into a dict.

```
files = glob('*.json')

list_of_df_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4 ']

data_dict = {name : pd.read_json(file) for name,file in zip(list_of_df_names,files)}

data_dict['name1']
```

another method using pathlib where we use the file name without the extension as the dict key. Note this will only work if your file names are unique.

```
fom pathlib import Path
path = 'path\to\jsons'

dict_ ={file.stem : pd.read_json(file) for file in Path(path).glob('*.json')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Andy L's answer:

```
files = glob('*.json')
dataframes = [pd.read_json(f) for f in files]
list_of_df_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
named_dfs = dict([n_df for n_df in zip(list_of_df_names, dataframes)])
```